# Stripe : Add new card to already created customer

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, stripe.js

I have a stripe customer already added, I am figuring out to add new card to customer. I searched around but couldn't found anything confirmed to asnwer my following questions.

1. Do stripe have any form of their own to add new card ?
2. Is following is the correct way to add new card ?

   ```
   $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve(Auth::user()->stripe_key);
   // Got the customer details successfully from the above call.  
   $card = $customer->cards->create(
     array( 
       "card" => 
         array( 
           "number"=> "4242424242424242", 
           "exp_month" => "12", 
           "exp_year" => "2016", 
           "cvc" => "123" 
         )
      )
   );
   ```

Comment: You need to create customer first, then retrieve that customer. and then `$customer->sources->create(array("source" => "tok_mastercard"));` 
have a look https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_card

Comment: @SafoorSafdar Please define `(array("source" => "tok_mastercard")` part of your comment, That is the part where i am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Stripe does not have a direct form specifically for adding a new card to a customer, however you can use Checkout or Elements to collect the customer's card details.

The process for adding a new card to a customer would be as follows:

1. Collect and tokenize the customer's card details using Checkout or Elements[0]. This will give you a Stripe token representing the card.
2. Send this token to your backend, where you can use something similar to the following code to save the card to the customer:

```
$token = $_POST['stripeToken']; #for example
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve(Auth::user()->stripe_key);
$customer->sources->create(array("source" => $token));
```

[0] - https://stripe.com/docs/checkout or https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart

[1] - https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_card